# Undefined variable $artikels in foreach laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have a problem with my laravel project where i can't show my data in the table. It keeps giving me undefined veriable $artikels in my writer.blade.php

So this is my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Artikel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArtikelController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $artikels = Artikel::all(); // Replace 'Artikel' with your actual model name

        return view('writer', compact('artikels'));
    }
}
```

this is my view in writer.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Judul</th>
            <th>Kategori</th>
            <th>Tag</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($artikels as $item)
        <tr>
            <td><img src="/gambar_artikel/{{ $item->gambar_artikel }}" width="100px"></td>
            <td>{{ $item->judul_artikel }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->kategori_artikel }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->tags_artikel }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
```

and this is my route

```
Route::view('/', 'dashboard')->name('dashboard');
Route::view('/AboutMe', 'aboutme')->name('AboutMe');
Route::view('/Writer', 'writer')->name('writer');


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::resource('/artikel', \App\Http\Controllers\ArtikelController::class);
```

how do i fix this problem? Thank you :)

I tried finding a lot of tutorials but it didn't fix my problem

Comment: did you `dd($artikels);` in your index function? What was the result? In your blade file you can also do `@dd($artikels)` and sew what you are getting from your controller

Comment: it returns the same error

Comment: if i just return $artikels and use postman, it returns my data.

Answer (score 0):

> Delete all temporary files from below folder.

Storage >> framework >> views >> *.php